# GNU parallel proper usage in conjunction with tar, xz, gpg

Tags: tar, gpg, gnu-parallel, xz

I would like to speed up my archiving operations, I am usually doing 23 GiB (one Blu-Ray) backups.

I have found this: [How to do large file parallel encryption using GnuPG and GNU parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46266489/1997354)

---

Since I don't understand this code at all (have never used `parallel`):

```
tar --create --format=posix --preserve-permissions --same-owner --directory $BASE/$name --to-stdout . |
    parallel --pipe --recend '' --keep-order --block-size 128M "xz -9 --check=sha256 |
    gpg --encrypt --recipient $RECIPIENT;echo bLoCk EnD" |
    pv > $TARGET/$FILENAME
```

---

**I would like to ask if anyone could kindly parse it for me.** Thank you.

Comment: It makes it easier to understand what level of understanding you have, if you can answer these questions: Have you watched the intro videos pi.dk/1? Have you read the cheat sheet https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_cheat.pdf? Have you walked through the tutorial `man parallel_tutorial`? Have you read chapter 1-2 of GNU Parallel 2018 (online: https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014)? Have you read chapter 9 of the book? Have you read the EXAMPLE section of `man parallel`? Have you read the rest of `man parallel`?

Comment: @OleTange Well, sadly No to all questions. Do you really think that this is relevant? For me to maybe include this info... Anyway, thank you for the perfect answer. I hope I will be fine now when adjusting it to my needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tar` run command `tar`.

`--create` create a tar archive.

`--format=posix` use the POSIX format of tar archive. This means you can extract it on other systems that support the POSIX format.

`--preserve-permissions` keep the same permissions on the files

`--same-owner` keep the same owner of the file (only relevant when extracting as root)

`--directory $BASE/$name` change to the dir $BASE/$name before starting

`--to-stdout` instead of saving to a file, send output to stdout

`.` tar the whole directory

`|` pipe stdout to next command

`parallel` run parallel

`--pipe` use pipe mode, so input on stdin will be given as input on stdin to the command to run (and not as command line arguments, which is the normal mode).

`--recend ''` Normally GNU Parallel splits on \n. Disable that because input is not text, but binary data.

`--keep-order` Make sure the output of the first command run is printed before the output of the second command - even if the second command finishes first.

`--block-size 128M` Pass a block of 128 MB of data to the command.

`"..."` the command to run

`|` pipe stdout to next command

`pv` show the speed of which data is sent

`> $TARGET/$FILENAME` redirect stdout to $TARGET/$FILENAME

GNU Parallel starts this command for each 128MB block:

`xz` the command xz

`-9` compress level 9

`--check=sha256` include integrity check in the output to be able to catch bit errors (e.g. on faulty disks).

`|` pipe stdout to next command

`gpg` the GNU Privacy Guard command

`--encrypt` encrypt data coming on stdin

`--recipient $RECIPIENT` use $RECIPIENT's key for encryption

`;` command separator

`echo bLoCk EnD` print bLoCk EnD